# gradle ear application packaging for multiple environment

Tags: gradle, war, ear

I have a web enterprise application that I am trying to automate building the EAR file for it with gradle (for the first time).

I have 2 projects

1 is the enterprise application APP_EAR and the other one is a dynamic web application APP that will be exported as a war file inside the main APP_EAR ear file.

I figured out how to use gradle to generate a war file for the dynamic web app, I am not sure how to use gradle to create the ear file that contains this war file.

The war file for my APP contains 3 tasks for each environment:

sys (system testing), qa (quality control) and prod for production

I created 3 tasks in the build.gradle for my APP like this:

```
task buildSys {
dependsOn copySys, war
}

task buildQa {
dependsOn copyQa, war
}

task buildProd {
dependsOn copyProd, war
}
```

the copySys, copyProd, etc... are just copy tasks that copies the appropriate configuration files for the environment I am targeting, before the war is created.

let's say I am creating a war file for sys , then I execute gradle buildSys

What I am trying to do is the following:

Assuming I want to create an EAR file for sys environment, I need to use gradle to perform those steps:

1) execute buildSys in the APP project to create a war file for sys environment
2) execute buildSysEAR that will package the created war file into an ear file.

I am not sure if I need to have 3 tasks in my build.gradle for APP_EAR to package the ear file for each environment or whether I can do it with one ear task and make it call the appropriate war task for that environment.

I just want to be able to execute one task that builds the war and the ear for this environment, I am not sure how to tie the war file to the ear file and/or trigger the correct build task for the war file from the APP_EAR build file.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Gradle supports creating an EAR using a plugin. You specify the WAR as a dependency and it will create the necessary files for you. (There is also a war plugin, it's simpler)

```
apply plugin: "ear"

dependencies
{
   deploy project("some support project")  // only necessary for ejb jars
   earlib "log4j:log4j:1.2.17:jar"
}

ear
{
   appDirName "EarContent" // or wherever, defaults to src/main/application

   deploymentDescriptor
   {
       displayName = "app-ear"
       description = "my application"

       web = project("APP")
       value = web.name + '-' + web.version + ".war"
       webModule( value , "/web-context")  // this is the important line, I need the version number
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I know about the ear plugin, but I did not know how to make it pick the right war build. In your example, it will build the war and then the ear, but how can I tell it to build the sys war or the qa war specifically? do I need 3 ear tasks in the same file?

Comment: yes, you would need different configurations, one for each war you want to build.

Answer (score 0):

Assume project A (EAR Project) has a build.gradle and within ear, the below code can be solve this - in this example assuming 'B' is a dynamic web application need to deploy within project 'A' -

```
plugins {
  id 'ear'
}

dependencies {
   deploy project(path:':b', configuration: 'archives')
}

ear{
     /* some basis configuration */
    libDirName 'APP-INF/lib'
    deploymentDescriptor {
      /* Some basic attributes */
      fileName = "application.xml"
      version = "8"
      def Set<Project> subProj = project.getSubprojects();
      subProj.each{proj -> 
        if(proj.name.contains("B")){
          webModule(proj.name + "-" + proj.version + ".war", "/"+ proj.name)
        } //if close
      }//each close
    }//deploymentDescriptor close

}//ear close
```